# Nodejs + csv data insert into table

Tags: node.js, csv

I am trying to insert data into table from csv file.

For example I have 3 row records in csv file. I need insert the data like async. (one by one then finally done).

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");
var fs = require("fs");

module.exports = function(app) {
    var offerLetterModel = app.models.offerletter;

    var stream = fs.createReadStream("test.csv");

    csv.fromStream(stream, {
            ignoreEmpty: true,
            headers: true,
        })
        .on("data", function(data) {    
            offerLetterModel.create({
                firstName: data.First_Name,
                lastName: data.Last_Name,
                emailId: data.Email,
                mobile: data.Mobile,
                address: data.Address,
            }, function(err, model) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("success");
                }
            });        
        })
        .on("end", function() {
            console.log("done");
        });

    //end    

};
```

Currently the Ouput:

```
done
success
success
success
```

Expected Output:

```
success
success
success
done
```

Comment: It's probably best if you store each line of data in an array and then do the creating/inserting on `end`

Comment: if we insert  large data means we have problem in this. ie) more than 1000 recrods.

Comment: Well the issue here is that `.create` is also async, so when `'end'` is called, it's likely that all data hasn't been inserted yet (which is what you're seeing). If you're worried about large amounts of data in a stream, there's npm modules to read csv's and convert to JSON which gives you one big JSON array at the end, which you can then insert into the database.